The Ball is not jumping
So i am making an HTML file but... the ball isn't jumping at all! here is the code if someone can help:


let dy = 2; // vertical speed
let interval;
let y; // Declare y outside the event listener function
let collision = false;

function startGame() {
  let circle = document.querySelector('.circle');
  y = parseInt(circle.style.top) || 10; // Initial top position
  let pad = document.querySelector('.pad');
  let padTop = window.innerHeight - pad.offsetHeight; // Get the top position of the pad

  console.log("Pad height:", pad.offsetHeight);
  console.log("Pad top position:", padTop);

  interval = setInterval(function() {
    // Check if the circle reaches the top of the pad
    if (y + circle.offsetHeight >= padTop) {
      clearInterval(interval); // Stop the circle
      dy = 0; // Reset vertical speed
      collision = true;
      circle.style.top = (padTop - circle.offsetHeight) + 'px'; // Correct position
      console.log("touchè")
    } else {
      collision = false; // Circle is not colliding with the pad
      // Move the circle downwards
      y += dy;
    }

    // Update circle position
    circle.style.top = y + 'px';
  }, 10); // Move every 10 milliseconds
}

// Add event listener for space bar key press
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.code === 'Space') {
    console.log(y);
    let circle = document.querySelector('.circle');
    if (collision) { // Only allow jumping when the circle is on the pad
      dy = -10; // Set the vertical speed to -10 to make the circle jump upwards
    } else {
      console.log("Nuh uh, jump when on pod. this ain't your double jump type shi..."); // Inform the user that jumping is only allowed when on the pad
    }
  }
});
body {
  background-color: royalblue;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans';
  margin: 0;
  /* Remove default margin */
  padding: 0;
  /* Remove default padding */
  cursor: default;
  position: relative;
  /* Add position relative to the body */
  height: 100vh;
  /* Ensure body takes full viewport height */
}

.button {
  background-color: rgb(0, 153, 255);
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* Adjust the radius as needed */
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: solid;
  top: 20px;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  right: 20px;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Change cursor on hover */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  /* Optional: to make the text visible on the button */
  text-align: center;
  /* Optional: to center the text */
}

.circle {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  /* Initial top position */
  left: 10px;
  /* Initial left position */
}

.pad {
  background-color: rgb(0, 25, 105);
  /* Changed color for better visibility */
  border-radius: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  /* Increased height for better visibility */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  /* Position it at the bottom */
  border: 2px solid black;
  /* Add a border to make it stand out */
  z-index: 10;
  /* Ensure it's on top of other elements */
  text-align: center;
  /* Center text inside pad */
  line-height: 50px;
  /* Center text vertically */
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Idle Game!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="pad">Pad</div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="button" onclick="startGame()">Start the game!</div>
</body>
</html>



i tried to add the Y in the event.key for the space BUT THEN IT ISN't FALLING!
i also tried to make the collision check (which worked) but it isn;t working still! WHy is the Y changing but the circle is at same place? Please someone help me!

Do you mean by "jump", the movements upward-downward? It seems like you are clearing the interval, if the ball is on the pad and stopping the movement clearInterval(interval); // Stop the circle;

Since you removed the timeout, setting the y speed has no effect.
Also, even if y speed is -10, you first check for the collision so that sets the speed to 0 again.

just keep the interval running
begin the interval by updating the position

Some tips:

For animation it's better to use requestAnimationFrame than setInterval
For animation it's much smoother to use style.transform.translate() for positioning the ball



let dy = 2; // vertical speed
let interval;
let y; // Declare y outside the event listener function
let collision = false;
let circle = document.querySelector('.circle');


function startGame() {
  y = parseInt(circle.style.top) || 10; // Initial top position
  let pad = document.querySelector('.pad');
  let padTop = window.innerHeight - pad.offsetHeight; // Get the top position of the pad

  console.log("Pad height:", pad.offsetHeight);
  console.log("Pad top position:", padTop);

  interval = setInterval(function() {
y += dy;

  
// Check if the circle reaches the top of the pad
if (y + circle.offsetHeight >= padTop) {
  dy = 0; // Reset vertical speed
  collision = true;
  circle.style.top = (padTop - circle.offsetHeight) + 'px'; // Correct position
  console.log("touchè")
} else {
  collision = false; // Circle is not colliding with the pad
  // Move the circle downwards
}

// Update circle position
circle.style.top = y + 'px';
  }, 10); // Move every 10 milliseconds
}

// Add event listener for space bar key press
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  console.log(event.code)
  if (event.code === 'Space') {
if (collision) { // Only allow jumping when the circle is on the pad
  dy = -10; // Set the vertical speed to -10 to make the circle jump upwards
} else {
  console.log("Nuh uh, jump when on pod. this ain't your double jump type shi..."); // Inform the user that jumping is only allowed when on the pad
}
  }
});
body {
  background-color: royalblue;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans';
  margin: 0;
  /* Remove default margin */
  padding: 0;
  /* Remove default padding */
  cursor: default;
  position: relative;
  /* Add position relative to the body */
  height: 100vh;
  /* Ensure body takes full viewport height */
}

.button {
  background-color: rgb(0, 153, 255);
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* Adjust the radius as needed */
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: solid;
  top: 20px;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  right: 20px;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Change cursor on hover */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  /* Optional: to make the text visible on the button */
  text-align: center;
  /* Optional: to center the text */
}

.circle {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  /* Initial top position */
  left: 10px;
  /* Initial left position */
}

.pad {
  background-color: rgb(0, 25, 105);
  /* Changed color for better visibility */
  border-radius: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  /* Increased height for better visibility */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  /* Position it at the bottom */
  border: 2px solid black;
  /* Add a border to make it stand out */
  z-index: 10;
  /* Ensure it's on top of other elements */
  text-align: center;
  /* Center text inside pad */
  line-height: 50px;
  /* Center text vertically */
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Idle Game!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="pad">Pad</div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="button" onclick="startGame()">Start the game!</div>
</body>
</html>




Actually your JS is making the ball to jump forever. what i want to make is to make the ball jump and then fall. But this code is fixing the issue that i asked for so, thanks!

Yes you can still improve a lot to create a realistic bouncy ball :) For example the closer the y position is to the ceiling, the slower the speed.
